# JNA - VM crashes when try to access to a C function with void* param

Tags: java, c, jna

I have the following code :

```
public class TTM {

public interface WrapperDLL extends Library {
    WrapperDLL INSTANCE = (WrapperDLL) Native.loadLibrary("TransportRE", WrapperDLL.class);

    int TRE_send(int channel, Pointer data, int len);

}
public int Send (int channel, String data, int len) {
    WrapperDLL wdll = WrapperDLL.INSTANCE;

    Memory mem = new Memory(data.length()+1);
    mem.setString(0, data);
    int byteSent = wdll.TRE_send(channel_id, mem.getPointer(0), len);
    // at this (TRE_send) point the VM crashes !!!!

  return byteSent;
}
```

}

taking a look at the JNA api I tried :

```
public int Send (int channel, String data, int len) {
    WrapperDLL wdll = WrapperDLL.INSTANCE;

    Memory mem = new Memory(data.length()+1);
    mem.setString(0, data);
    int byteSent = wdll.TRE_send(channel_id, mem, len);

  return byteSent;
}
```

This time does not crashes but it not works properly (byteSent = 0!)

Some hint ?

Comment: Could you show how your native function is declared?

Comment: This is the declaration of the method ... 
int TRE_send(int channel, const void *data, int len);

I tried adding +1 (as suggested by technomage) to :
int byteSent = wdll.TRE_send(channel_id, mem, len+1);

the byteSent=1 .... I think still something wrong.

thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you make sure that `len` isnot 0? Also, are you sure that you don't want to do `len = data.length()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve fix it !

```
int byteSent = wdll.TRE_send(channel_id, data.toCharArray(), len);
```

since the 2nd parameter is a void* but in the dll code the first thing is to cast it to char * I used the same type and now it works.

for sure this is not a "general solution" since the "TRE_send" want a void* type ... 
what do you think ?

bye

Answer (score 1):

You are dereferencing your `String` as if it contained a pointer rather than character data.

`Pointer.getPointer(0)` attempts to extract a pointer value from the given pointer address; you definitely want to pass the pointer value directly as in your second snippet.

JNA allows you to pass a `String` value directly, automatically converting it into a C string (NUL-terminated array of bytes).  However, it's not clear that your native method wants a string; it may want a specially formatted byte buffer.

If `len` is intended to be the length of the buffer you're sending, then it should be the length of the string plus one (or the size of the `Memory` that you're passing).

**EDIT**

You imply that the DLL always casts to `char *`, in which case you should simply pass the `String` as-is.  If your DLL sometimes expects non-ASCII data, then you should pass `Memory` and use its member functions to write the desired data.  Note that you can define multiple versions of your DLL with different signatures, e.g.

```
  void send(String);
  void send(Pointer);
  void send(MyStructure);
```